# Landscape PDF page orientation with wrong orientation in mediabox information

Tags: pdf

I have been looking for a solution for this problem :
I'm using python ReportLab canvas to generate overlay(watermark) document from source document
and merge it into source pdf document (with PyPDF2).
Summary i have two landscape-oriented A0 single pages pdfs.
I want to overlay(watermarking) them in a manner that the resulting single page pdf contains both pages merged,
but with the same denisity.
But result (merged) document contains watermark that were rotated by 90 against source document

print(source.rect.width, source.rect.height)         giving next result 5102.0 2384.0
but
print(source.mediabox.width, source.mediabox.height) giving next result 2384.0 5102.0

Problem that Source document looks landscape-oriented on devices and printers but
has structure in pdf :
Rotate 90
MediaBox [ 0 0 2384 5102 ]

watermark page has next structure in pdf
MediaBox [ 0 0 5102 2384 ]
Rotate 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the rotation of a page to 0 whilst counter-rotating its dimensions and page content to compensate - resulting in a visually-unchanged file - using cpdf's `-upright` operation:

`cpdf -upright in.pdf -o out.pdf`

Preprocessing your files in this manner should let your overlay function operate as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code now works!!! Amazing solution!!!